# Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 in late 2021

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade

I got access to a computer using Ubuntu 16.04. Since it is out of support, I am in need to upgrade it to, say, 20.x.

To do this, I am prompted to execute `sudo apt-get update` before. But this gives the following error messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253
W: Failed to fetch https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial-cran35/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253
E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I assume that some have-a-look-see-URL became invalid. (especially probably `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/Packages`) What is / are the correct URL(s) and how to teach them to apt-get?

Until now, I have not saved important data / programs on the HDD, therefore backups are not relevant.

Additionally, using an external medium is not allowed.

PS: This post was created on this site thanks to @john-jones.

EDIT: Replacing `security.(...)` and `de.archive.(...)` by `old-releases.(...)` did not work, since the stem does not refer to a site ([here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/)) containing xenial-xerus (16.04). Going up via "Parent directory" and going to xenial-xerus ([here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/) -> [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) -> [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/)) did not yield a page containing a folder named "Packages" or something similar. I am confused. :-)

Comment: If you don’t have anything important on the computer, why not just fresh-install a supported version?

Comment: Are those the only errors you get ? All third-party repositories/ppa's should be disabled, and the Ubuntu ones changed to old-releases.ubuntu.com/... as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @SorenA: These were the only warnings / errors, the only notable line begins before were "Ign:", e. g. Ign:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease

Comment: @cocomac: I have no external mediums at hand / are not allowed to use them.

Comment: If you can't purchase a USB flash drive, borrow one.  You're going to want to have it anyway in case the upgrade fails. 16.04 support has ended and there is no guarantee of successful upgrade.

Comment: The old-releases change does **not** apply to releases that have ESM support; 16.04 has ESM support (so it's end of *standard* support, not *extended* support). You need to have ESM enabled to fully upgrade your system, then you can *release-upgrade* to 18.04.  Your error is a 3rd party repo (which are welcome to *drop* the release once it's past it's 5 years;  meaning post 2021-April) so it being gone shouldn't be a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to launch Software & Updates (or `software-properties-gtk` command) and then disable *`http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04`* from it. Or use text editor. This repository is no longer exists.

Please also make sure that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain the following lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

And remove ESM list by `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list` to prevent unexpected behaviour.

To restore R GPG key you have to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Then you have to:

1. update package lists by

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. install all new dependencies for 16.04 LTS existing system using

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
3. remove R packages to prevent their possible conflict on upgrade to 18.04 LTS using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1367607/66509) (steps 1 to 3).
4. reboot
5. set your release upgrade way as LTS to LTS using commands below:

   ```
   sudo sed -i "s/^Prompt=never/Prompt=lts/" /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   sudo sed -i "s/^Prompt=normal/Prompt=lts/" /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   ```
6. run distribution upgrade to 18.04 LTS using `sudo do-release-upgrade` or `update-manager -c` .
7. reinstall R packages on 18.04 LTS using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1367607/66509) (steps 4 to 5)
8. reboot
9. run distribution upgrade to 20.04 LTS using `sudo do-release-upgrade` or `update-manager -c` .
10. reboot
11. enjoy